# Unit testing a directive - Unable to force a fake data

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, angularjs-directive

I'm trying to understand how to unit test my directive in my situation below.

Basically I'm trying to unit test a directive which has a controller. On the loading of this directive the controller makes a http request by a service which brings some data to the controller again then provides this data to the directive view.

On the scenario below in my understanding I should do:

- A $httpBackend to avoid an exception when the http request is done;
- Populate the fake data to be able to unit test the directive with diff behaviors
- Compile the directive

What I've been trying so far, as you can see, is override the Service with the fake data. What I could not make work so far.

Some doubts come up now.

As you can see in my Controller. I'm providing the whole Service to the view:

> $scope.ItemsDataservice = ItemsDataservice;

What makes me believe that my approach to override the Service should work.

**My question:**

On scenario below I understand that I could override the Service to manipulate the data or even override the controller to manipulate the data by scope.

What's the right thing to do here?
Am I understand wrong?
Am I mixing the unit tests?

In my current unit test code, when I'm applying the fake data(or not), is not make any difference:

> *ItemsDataservice*.items = DATARESULT;
>
> *ItemsDataservice*.items = null;

**Controller**:

```
angular.module('app')
    .controller('ItemsCtrl', function ($scope, $log, ItemsDataservice) {

        $scope.ItemsDataservice = ItemsDataservice;
        $scope.ItemsDataservice.items = null;

        $scope.loadItems = function() {

            var items = [];

            ItemsDataservice.getItems().then(function(resp) {

                if (resp.success != 'false') {

                    for (resp.something ... ) {
                        items.push({ ... });
                    };

                    ItemsDataservice.items = items;

                };

            }, function(e) {
                $log.error('Error', e);
            });
        };

        $scope.loadItems();

    });
```

**Service**:

```
angular.module('app')
    .service('ItemsDataservice', function ItemsDataservice($q, $http) {

        ItemsDataservice.getItems = function() {

            var d = $q.defer();
            var deffered = $q.defer();
            var url = 'http://some-url?someparameters=xxx'

            $http.get(url)
                .success(function (d) {
                    deffered.resolve(d);
                });

            return deffered.promise;

        };

        return ItemsDataservice;

    });
```

**Directive**:

```
angular.module('app')
    .directive('items', function () {
        return {
            templateUrl: '/items.html',
            restrict: 'A',
            replace: true,
            controller: 'ItemsCtrl'
        };
    });
```

**Unit testing directive**:

```
ddescribe('Directive: Items', function () {

  var element, scope, _ItemsDataservice_, requestHandler, httpBackend;
  var URL = 'http://some-url?someparameters=xxx';
  var DATARESULT = [{ ... }];

  // load the directive's module
  beforeEach(module('app'));
  beforeEach(module('Templates')); // setup in karma to get template from .html

  beforeEach(inject(function ($rootScope, ItemsDataservice) {

    httpBackend = $httpBackend;
    scope = $rootScope.$new();
    _ItemsDataservice_ = ItemsDataservice;

    requestHandler = httpBackend.when('GET', URL).respond(200, 'ok');

  }));

  afterEach(function() {
    //httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingExpectation();
    //httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingRequest();
  });

  it('Show "No Items available" when empty result', inject(function ($compile) {

    _ItemsDataservice_.items = null;

    element = angular.element('<div data-items></div>');
    element = $compile(element)(scope);
    scope.$digest();

    element = $(element);
    expect(element.find('.msg_noresult').length).toBe(1);

  }));

  it('Should not show "No Items available" when data available ', inject(function ($compile) {

    _ItemsDataservice_.items = DATARESULT;

    element = angular.element('<div data-items></div>');
    element = $compile(element)(scope);
    scope.$digest();

    element = $(element);
    expect(element.find('.msg_noresult').length).toBe(0);

  }));

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I sorted out the problem.

Changed this line:

> element = $compile(element)(scope);

To this line:

> element = $compile(element.contents())(scope);

The only diff is the jquery method **.contents()**

I did not get yet why. But it solved.

**Update**:

Another thing I've just discovered and that was really useful for me.
You can use regular expression on you httpBackend:

```
httpBackend.whenGET(/.*NameOfThePageXXX\.aspx.*/).respond(200, 'ok');
```

So, you don't need to worry to use exactly the same parameters etc if you just want to avoid an exception.